# Get ID of inserted row with Propel ORM when not using autoincremented IDs

Tags: php, pdo, propel2

Using Propel, I can save an object using

```
$user = new User;
$user->setName('Test');
$user->save();
```

`$user->getId()` will contain the ID of the inserted object. But this will only work if I use autoincremented ID values.

Is there any way I can get this to work when the IDs are generated by a function?

I can append `RETURNING id` to the end of the insert queries to return the ID, but I'm not sure whether I can get this data back into the Propel User object.

Comment: If it's generated by a function, can you get it before creating the object? and set it like `->setId($yourId)`?

Comment: It gets generated by a function in Postgres so doesn't exist until it has been inserted.

Comment: Noticed I can add `$this->id = $stmt->fetch()['id'];` into the `doInsert()` method in my Propel generated class which works but I'd love a nicer solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to retrieve the missing (externally created) values by calling `reload()` on the object you wish to hydrate.

```
//hydrates fields by database values
$user->reload();
//should return the postgresql-generated-value
$user->getId();
```

**edit**: typos

Comment: Hi Eelke, I get an error saying `"Cannot find matching row in the database to reload object values."` when I try to do `reload()` after `save()`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi James, sorry for the delay. Could you post your schema for this specific model? I once used a uuid_generate function to generate my primary keys and had no trouble retrieving the new value with the help of reload().

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a function or trigger in MySQL that creates for you a ID automatically on each insert then you need to save this generated value per session/connection. For example using `last_insert_id(new_id)`, so you can fetch this value using `SELECT last_insert_id();` through the current connection in PHP. There's no other logical way to fetch such generated IDs by functions/triggers.